# Controle de tentativas de login pelo PHP

Tags: php

Preciso disponibilizar um acesso externo para um pequenos sistema de relatórios, porém, não sei como fazer o controle de tentativas de login já que terei que validar o acesso usando a tabela de usuários de um software terceiro, portanto não posso alterar as tabelas.

Como o uso de cookies não é indicado e também não consegui implementar o reCaptcha com o acesso interno. Neste caso existe algum tipo de controle que possa ser aplicado nessa situação utilizando somente o PHP?

Comment: Eu prefiro capturar o IP e colocar num arquivo de log. Sessão num instante que o usuario limpar o histórico do navegador tudo se perde.

Comment: Verificar esse arquivo de log não vai deixar o login lento? Sobre a sessão, isso se aplica também em força bruta?

Comment: O Laravel tem um sistema assim. Eles utilizam um sistema de cache, combinado com informações enviadas para o Http Header. A cada tentativa ele pega o valor anterior do Header e adiciona +1.

Comment: Você fala de um cache server-side? Isso parece interessante. Vou dar uma pesquisada na documentação do PHP. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar SESSION.

Pra cada tentativa, incrementa uma variável na $_SESSION e grava também o horário que o cara tentou. Se teve mais de tantas tentativas na última hora ou algo assim, trava.

Comment: Acabei focando tantos nas soluções já apresentadas pela comunidade que acabei ignorando a existência do SESSION. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Daí o cara limpa o Cookie do navegador, e ele pode "começar do zero" novamente, né. Essa é a única falha desse método. Usar Sessão e usar Cookie dá na mesma. A sessão depende do Cookie para funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma implementação completa com número de tentativas e reCaptcha que estou usando em um site que estou desenvolvendo, a única coisa que falta pra funcionar 100% é criar os objetos, mas deixei bem descrito como criá-los, sou apenas estudante então fiz o melhor que pude.

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); ini_set('display_startup_erros',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?><!--Força o php a mostrar todo tipo de erro, linha temporária-->
    <?php
    function __autoload($class_name){
        require_once '../_lib/'.$class_name.'.php';//-->lê minhas classes de forma automática
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/login.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#send').prop('disabled', true);//desativa o botão enviar
                $('.g-recaptcha').hide();//esconde o captcha
                validate();
                $('#inputEmail, #inputPassword').change(validate);
            });
            function validate() {
                if ($('#inputEmail').val().length > 10) {//enquanto o campo de email nao tiver menos que 10 caracteres, não ativa o reCaptcha
                    $('.g-recaptcha').show();//exibe o reCaptcha
                }else{//se mudar de ideia e reduzir o campo pra menos de 10 caracteres...
                    $('.g-recaptcha').hide();//o reCaptcha se esconde novmanete
                }
            }
            function enableSend() {
                $('#send').prop('disabled', false);//quando o captcha é confirmado, ativa o botao enviar
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $helper = new Helpers();//-->objeto com vários métodos importantes
    if (isset($_POST['attempt'])){//verifica se tem tentativa restante
        $attempt = intval($helper->validation($_POST['attempt']));//validation=método que verifica e escapa minha sring (trim(), stripcslashes() e htmlspecialchars())
    }else{
        $attempt = 3;//se não for definido número de tentativas, aqui é definido como 3
    }

    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) and isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) {//garante que todos os campos foram preenchidos
        $captcha_data = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        if ($captcha_data) {//Verificação do reCaptcha
            $resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=DIGITE-SUA-CHAVE-SECRETA-GERADA-PELO-GOOGLE-AQUI=" . $captcha_data . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            if ($resposta) {//validação do reCaptcha
                $username = strtolower($helper->validation($_POST['username']));
                $password = $helper->validation($_POST['password']);
                $user = new User();//--->meu objeto que acessa o banco de dados usando PDO
                $userValidated = $user->checkPasswordHash($username);//--->método do meu objeto que procura o usuario no bacno de dados (SELECT * FROM tbl_Users WHERE username = $username)
                if ($userValidated){//verifica se o email existe, se existir...
                    if ($userValidated->status == 1){//verifica se a conta está bloqueada ou não
                        echo 'Essa conta está bloqueada, criar botão para reenviar o email de recuperação...';
                    }else{
                    $hash = $userValidated->password;//retorna o hash do password
                    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {//compara a senha e o hash que foi criado usando password_hash() e salvo no banco de dados
                        echo 'Password é válido, inserir código que inicia as sessões e chama a próxima página';//-->insira seu código
                    } else {//caso o password estjeja errado, perde uma tentativa
                        if ($attempt != 1){//se a tentativa restante for igual a 1, a proxima vez será direcionado para a página de recuperação de senha
                            $attempt--;
                            echo 'Usuário e senha não combinam, você tem mais '.$attempt.' tentativas';//mostra o número de tentativas restante
                        }else{//bloqueia a conta e chama a página de recuperação de senha
                            echo 'inserir código que bloqueia a conta e abre pagina de recuperaçao de senha';//-->insira seu código de bloqueio
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }else{//se o email não existir, perde uma tentativa mas não avisa se o erro foi no email ou na senha
                    if ($attempt != 0){
                        $attempt--;
                        echo 'Usuário e senha não combinam, você tem mais '.$attempt.' tentativas';//mostra o número de tentativas restante
                    }else{//bloqueia a conta e chama a página de recuperação de senha
                        echo 'inserir código que bloqueia a conta e abre pagina de recuperaçao de senha';//-->insira seu código de bloqueio
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Validação não concluída, tente novamente.";
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            echo "Validação não concluída, tente novamente.";
            exit;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <section>
        <form class="login" action="login.php" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>
                <label for="inputEmail" class="Label">Email: </label>
                <input id="inputEmail" class="inputText" type="email" maxlength="30" name="username" required>
                <label for="inputPassword" class="Label">Password: </label>
                <input id="inputPassword" class="inputPassword" type="password" maxlength="20" name="password" required>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="DIGITE-A-CHAVE-DO-SEU-SITE-CRIADA-PELO-GOOGLE-AQUI" data-callback="enableSend"></div><!--Linha que adiciona o recaptcha-->
                <input type="hidden" name="attempt" value=<?php echo $attempt ?> /><!--envia por post o numero de tentativas restante-->
                <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" id="send" class="send">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </section>

    </body>
    </html>
```